# Can I multiply two dummy variables together?

Tags: regression

Are there any rules about multiplying dummy variables in a regression?

For example can I say:
y = D1*D2*x1 + x2 + x3

Would I be able to state D1*D2 as I want both criteria to be met before x1 is included?

Would the correct  notation then be as follows?
D =  [1, 1], D has occurred at time t
[0, 0], otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that as long as the resulting product is not always 1 or 0 (e.g. multiplying male and female dummy). There is no special rule about what you propose other than the regular caveats that apply to regression with dummies.